# find sum of duplicate values?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-3.0

I want to find duplicate ISBN as Distinct and their total quantity as sum.
[image]

i want **ISBN = 9789** total quantity as **509** and **ISBN = 978944** total quantity as **194**

i am using code as given below

```
`array('fields'=> array('ERPBookdetail.id','ERPBookdetail.item','ERPBookdetail.book_id','ERPBookdetail.isbn','ERPBookdetail.title',
                                'ERPBookdetail.class','ERPBookdetail.subject','ERPBookdetail.medium','ERPBookdetail.board','ERPBookdetail.edition'
                                ,'ERPBookdetail.db_type','ERPBookdetail.price','ERPOrderDetail.item','ERPOrder.order_id','ERPBookdetail.qty','SUM(ERPBookdetail.qty) as total_quantity'),
                'group' => array('ERPBookdetail.isbn'),
               'order'=>'total_quantity DESC',
              'joins' => array(
                        array(
                    'table' => 'orders',
                    'alias' => 'ERPOrder',
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                        'conditions' => array('OR' => array(
                                                        array('ERPOrder.confirmation' => 1),array('ERPOrder.confirmation' => 'Yes'),
                                    )),
                            ),
        array('table' => 'order_details',
        'alias' => 'ERPOrderDetail',
        'type' => 'INNER',
        'conditions' =>array('ERPOrderDetail.item = ERPBookdetail.item','ERPOrder.order_id = ERPOrderDetail.order_id'),)),)
);`
```

Comment: The query you need is: `SELECT isbn, SUM(qty) FROM mytable GROUP BY isbn` I don't know how to do it in cakePHP unfortunately.

Comment: I dont know how to do it in sql but to do it in php check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150063/in-php-merge-duplicate-set-of-elements-of-an-multidimensional-array-and-sum-the

Comment: May be this one would help..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971148/sum-function-in-cakephp-query

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in mysql by simply

```
    select isbn, sum(qty) as qty from table group by isbn
```

if you dont want to change mysql query then in php you can it by this way

```
   for($isbn_rec = 0 ; $isbn_rec < count($your_outputarray_from_query); $isbn_rec++)
   {
      $new_array[$your_outputarray_from_query['isbn']]['qty'] += $your_outputarray_from_query['qty'];
      // if any isbn records comes again then it will be sum up with older isbn number
   }
```

and you will get final array as below

```
  array('9789'=>    array('qty'=>'509')
'978944'=> array('qty'->'194')
  )
```